# How to convert a single column to multiple

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following data in this format:

[image: Original Data]

I wish to transform the data to look like the following format:

[image: Final Data]

I have tried the following:

Column F uses WEEKNUM to find the week number of the year, but the format is down one single column when I want it to be applied across the way as seen in the second screenshot. Using IF didn't work as it would refer to the same cell, nor VLOOKUPs. I also tried a PivotTable, but then the ID sort changes from (WG1, WG2, WG3 etc) to (WG10, WG11..., WG19, WG20 etc) which I do not want. It also combines the years (2022/2023).

Anyone any idea how I can do this without manually entering the data? A formula/VBA/excel action to quickly make the original screenshot look like the following? (The column headers - 48, 49, 50 etc are already in place) Bit stumped. I am capable with VBA as well hence the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have started entering the values 48, 49, ... manually, but you might decide to use the `UNIQUE()` function for that purpose.
Once you have this, you can easily use the following simple formula:

```
=IF($B2=D$1,$C2,"")
```

In order to understand, hereby the corresponding screenshot:

[image]

Have fun :-)

Comment: You champion, I was so close as well! Feel proper stupid ahah, thank you so much I have been banging my head on this, have good holidays! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 current channel then you can use:

```vb
=LET(weeknum,TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(Tabelle1[week num])),
values,IF(Tabelle1[week num]=weeknum,Tabelle1[qty due],""),
VSTACK(weeknum,values))
```

[image]

if you don't have current channel (but Excel 365) you can use two formulas:

- E1: `TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(Tabelle1[week num]))`
- E2: `IF(Tabelle1[week num]=E$1,Tabelle1[qty due],"")`

Comment: Hello, sorry I am confused, what is Tabelle1? I cant see any cell references, so this concept is unknown to me and I am just getting errors using your solution. Also, my version of Excel is Version 2211 Build 16.0.15831.20098

Comment: sorry - "Tabelle1" is the table from A1 to C5 (by using Insert > table from the ribbon)